# How do I improve the speed on this python script?

Tags: python

A while ago I started getting into sim racing, but because I can't afford a wheel myself, I searched for ways I could emulate it, so I stumbled upon an application that lets me write scripts in python with certain libraries: https://andersmalmgren.github.io/FreePIE/.
The thing is, this script that I have tends to lag a lot, like, when I hold X (key to alternate between full-braking and braking just a quarter) the more I hold it, the more it delays after I release the key, this also happens when I use the clutch key (C), and the "Smooth Throttle" key (Z), I think this has to do with the way I programmed it (spaghetti pretty much, as I don't know a lot of python) so I thought I could get help from this forum, also It's my first time and this is my fresh new account, so I could be doing something wrong here, but anyways, here's the code:

```
if starting:    
    system.setThreadTiming(TimingTypes.HighresSystemTimer)
    system.threadExecutionInterval = 5
    
    def set_button(button, key):
        if keyboard.getKeyDown(key):
            v.setButton(button, True)
        else:
            v.setButton(button, False)
    
    def calculate_rate(max, time):
        if time > 0:
            return max / (time / system.threadExecutionInterval)
        else:
            return max

    int32_max = (2 ** 14) - 1
    activate = True
    int32_min = (( 2** 14) * -1) + 1
    
    v = vJoy[0]
    v.x, v.y, v.z, v.rx, v.ry, v.rz, v.slider, v.dial = (int32_min,) * 8

    # =============================================================================================
    # Axis inversion settings (multiplier): normal = 1; inverted = -1
    # =============================================================================================
    global throttle_inversion, braking_inversion, clutch_inversion
    throttle_inversion = 1
    braking_inversion = 1
    clutch_inversion = 1
    
    # =============================================================================================
    # Mouse settings
    # =============================================================================================
    global mouse_sensitivity, sensitivity_center_reduction
    mouse_sensitivity = 4.0
    
    sensitivity_center_reduction = 1.0
    
    # =============================================================================================
    # Ignition cut settings
    # =============================================================================================
    global ignition_cut_time, ignition_cut_elapsed_time
    ignition_cut_enabled = True
    ignition_cut_time = 100
    ignition_cut_elapsed_time = 0
    
    global ignition_cut, ignition_cut_released
    # Init values, do not change
    ignition_cut = False
    ignition_cut_released = True
    
    # =============================================================================================
    # Steering settings
    # =============================================================================================
    global steering, steering_max, steering_min, steering_center_reduction    
    # Init values, do not change
    steering = 0.0
    steering_max = float(int32_max)
    steering_min = float(int32_min)
    steering_center_reduction = 1.0
    
    # =============================================================================================
    # Throttle settings
    # =============================================================================================
    global throttle_blip_enabled
    throttle_blip_enabled = False
    
    # In milliseconds
    throttle_increase_time = 300
    throttle_increase_time_after_ignition_cut = 0
    throttle_increase_time_blip = 50
    throttle_decrease_time = 300
    
    global throttle, throttle_max, throttle_min
    # Init values, do not change
    throttle_max = int32_max * throttle_inversion
    throttle_min = int32_min * throttle_inversion
    throttle = throttle_min
    
    global throttle_increase_rate, throttle_decrease_rate
    # Set throttle behaviour with the increase and decrease time,
    # the actual increase and decrease rates are calculated automatically
    throttle_increase_rate = calculate_rate(throttle_max, throttle_increase_time)
    throttle_increase_rate_after_ignition_cut = calculate_rate(throttle_max, throttle_increase_time_after_ignition_cut) 
    throttle_increase_rate_blip = calculate_rate(throttle_max, throttle_increase_time_blip)
    throttle_decrease_rate = calculate_rate(throttle_max, throttle_decrease_time) * -1  
    # =============================================================================================
    # Braking settings
    # =============================================================================================
    # In milliseconds
    braking_increase_time = 160
    braking_decrease_time = 130
    
    global braking, braking_max, braking_min
    # Init values, do not change
    braking_max = int32_max * braking_inversion
    braking_min = int32_min * braking_inversion
    braking = braking_min
    
    global braking_increase_rate, braking_decrease_rate
    # Set braking behaviour with the increase and decrease time,
    # the actual increase and decrease rates are calculated automatically
    braking_increase_rate = calculate_rate(braking_max, braking_increase_time)
    braking_decrease_rate = calculate_rate(braking_max, braking_decrease_time) * -1
    
    # =============================================================================================
    # Clutch settings
    # =============================================================================================   
    # In milliseconds
    clutch_increase_time = 0
    clutch_decrease_time = 50
    
    global clutch, clutch_max, clutch_min
    # Init values, do not change
    clutch_max = int32_max * clutch_inversion
    clutch_min = int32_min * clutch_inversion
    clutch = clutch_min
    
    global clutch_increase_rate, clutch_decrease_rate
    # Set clutch behaviour with the increase and decrease time,
    # the actual increase and decrease rates are calculated automatically
    clutch_increase_rate = calculate_rate(clutch_max, clutch_increase_time)
    clutch_decrease_rate = calculate_rate(clutch_max, clutch_decrease_time) * -1


# assign button


# =================================================================================================
# LOOP START
# =================================================================================================

# =================================================================================================
# Activate
# =================================================================================================
if keyboard.getPressed(Key.End):
    activate = not activate
    
if activate == True:
    vJoy[0].setButton(0,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.S)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(1,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.D)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(2,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.C)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(3,int(mouse.wheelUp))
    vJoy[0].setButton(4,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Home)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(5,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.G)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(6,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.H)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(7,int(mouse.wheelDown))
else:
    vJoy[0].setButton(0,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Home)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(1,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Home)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(2,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Home)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(3,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Home)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(4,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Home)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(5,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Home)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(6,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Home)))
    vJoy[0].setButton(7,int(keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Home)))

# =================================================================================================

# =================================================================================================
# Steering logic
# =================================================================================================
if steering > 0:
    steering_center_reduction = sensitivity_center_reduction ** (1 - (steering / steering_max))
elif steering < 0:
    steering_center_reduction = sensitivity_center_reduction ** (1 - (steering / steering_min))

steering = steering + ((float(mouse.deltaX) * mouse_sensitivity) / steering_center_reduction)

if steering > steering_max:
    steering = steering_max
elif steering < steering_min:
    steering = steering_min

v.x = int(round(steering))

# =================================================================================================
# Clutch logic
# =================================================================================================
if keyboard.getPressed(Key.C):
    throttle = -16383
if keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.C):
    clutch = clutch + clutch_increase_rate
else:
    clutch = clutch + clutch_decrease_rate

if clutch > clutch_max * clutch_inversion:
    clutch = clutch_max * clutch_inversion
elif clutch < clutch_min * clutch_inversion:
    clutch = clutch_min * clutch_inversion

v.z = clutch
# =================================================================================================
# Smooth Throttle
# =================================================================================================
if keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.Z):
    blip = 1
elif keyboard.getKeyUp(Key.Z):
    blip = 200
# =================================================================================================
# Brake y Full Brake
# =================================================================================================
if keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.X):
    maxBrake = 16383
elif keyboard.getKeyUp(Key.X):
    maxBrake = 2048
elif keyboard.getKeyDown(Key.J):
    maxBrake = 1
# =================================================================================================
# Throttle logic
# =================================================================================================
if mouse.leftButton:
    throttle = throttle + throttle_increase_rate * blip
else:
    throttle = throttle + throttle_decrease_rate * blip

if throttle > throttle_max * throttle_inversion:
    throttle = throttle_max * throttle_inversion
elif throttle < throttle_min * throttle_inversion:
    throttle = throttle_min * throttle_inversion

v.y = throttle

# =================================================================================================
# Braking logic
# =================================================================================================
if mouse.rightButton:
    braking = braking + (braking_increase_rate*6)
else:
    if braking > 4096:
            braking = braking + (braking_decrease_rate * 4)
    else:
        braking = braking + (braking_decrease_rate * 4)
        
if braking > maxBrake:
    braking = maxBrake
elif braking < braking_min * braking_inversion:
    braking = braking_min * braking_inversion


v.rz = braking

# =================================================================================================
# Buttons post-throttle logic
# =================================================================================================
#set_button(look_left_button, look_left_key)
#set_button(look_right_button, look_right_key)
#set_button(look_back_button, look_back_key)
#set_button(change_view_button, change_view_key)
#set_button(indicator_left_button, indicator_left_key)
#set_button(indicator_right_button, indicator_right_key)

# =================================================================================================
# PIE diagnostics logic
# =================================================================================================
diagnostics.watch(v.x)
diagnostics.watch(v.y)
diagnostics.watch(v.rz)
diagnostics.watch(maxBrake)
diagnostics.watch(blip)
diagnostics.watch(activate)
```

to test the code you simply copy this into a .py file and run it with freePIE, it has a watch tool that is very useful too

I tried to use and modify an already found script for emulating a wheel in Assetto Corsa through freePIE, since the beginning and even before I modified it, It began to lag a lot, like it's buffering a lot of inputs innecesarily.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I cannot reproduce this behaviour on my machine (win 10, intel i7, 16GB). No matter how long I press X or Z, maxBrake and blip instantly change their value upon key release. Do I have to press something in parallel to get to the described malfunction?

Comment: Nope, and sorry for the late reply, as it is 8:18 AM for me rn.
Probably happens only when running the script while being in game also, I'm going to tryy right now, aaand yes, this sure does not happen when you only run the script, could it be that my CPU is getting too much work just to play the game? It's assetto corsa, and it is known for being pretty cpu expensive

Comment: no worries about late replies, this is an international site, and hence time zone discrepancies are expected. To test your hypothesis, try to limit the game's CPU affinity to certain cores and Freepie to others. See e.g. https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-limit-cpu-usage-program/#:~:text=Task%20Manager%20will%20highlight%20the,want%20the%20process%20to%20use. on how to do that

Comment: yes, this makes it so the game is very laggy but now the freePIE script goes smooth, so the problem was assetto corsa eating too much cpu ?

Comment: yes, it seems so. I do not see much improvement potential in the script, as it just polls buttons and is widely used (found a youtube video explaining how to use it in a, none of the comments mentioned anything about lags). Maybe you find some "balanced" cpu-affinity where both the script and the game work "smooth enough".